How To Import an ICS into Exchange using EWS & Powershell
So I am trying to import Appointments/Meetings with attendees into Exchange and I am very much struggling.
There are a few examples given for appointments with no attendees, however what are you supposed to do if you do want attendees?
Importantly I am trying to import from an ICS / MIMEContent file.
The main guide I am following are based around this microsoft page
Example code snippet:
$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8 
$mimeBytes = $enc.GetBytes($mime)
#$mime here is the mimecontent file, loaded in as a string.

$mimeContent = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MimeContent 
$mimeContent.CharacterSet = "UTF8" #also tried 'UTF-8' and a few other things
$mimeContent.Content = $mimeBytes

#$ExchangeService is my service connection to EWS
#$impersonateAddress is the meeting recipient email address 
$ExchangeService.ImpersonatedUserId = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress, $impersonateAddress)

$ImpersonatedFolder = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderID([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Calendar, $impersonateAddress)

$Appointment = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment($ExchangeService) 
$Appointment.MimeContent = $mimeContent

$Appointment.Save($ImpersonatedFolder)
#also tried:
#$Appointment.Save([Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.SendInvitationsMode]::SendToNone)
#$Appointment.Save($ImpersonatedFolder, [Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.SendInvitationsMode]::SendToNone)

I know quite a few of the guides say its not recommended to import appointments with attendees, due to the relationships between various attendees' copies. However surely there is a way of doing this!
Also I haven't given an example MimeContent file, however this is a standard ics file that has been loaded into the file a bit earlier - which is why I am converting it to bytes.

What's the source system where your ics file are coming from ? if its exchange then you could use ExportItem on the source and UploadItem on the destination which would give you a full fidelity import.
Are you trying to import the meeting into the original organizers mailbox? the EWS/store parser that Exchange uses won't import attendees so in EWS your only option is to re-create or re-accept the meetings.
